# Why was Gai resurrected?

Tags: guilty-crown

If Daath was after the king's power, they could have taken it from Shu anytime they wanted. Why wait so long and resurrect Gai for taking the king's power? They had someone else who could use king's power as well. Why does it have to be Gai?

And what caused a change of plans? Keido tried to be the "Adam". Then it was Gai.

Comment: As this is opinion, I will leave this as comment:  It could be due to the fact that Daath seems to, i don't know, have a thing for manipulating things from the outside, that is, to have others do their work for them.  That, and it would make the story less interesting.  Kind of like why didn't certain hobbits just get the giant eagles to FLY them to a certain mountain to fulfill a certain task.

Answer (score 1):

It was revealed that Gai was the original Adam, the mate created for Mana. The plan was to resurrect Gai in order to get him to obtain the power of kings from Shu which meant severing his arm. Haruka Ouma, Shu's step mom went along with this plan because she didn't want Shu's fate to be the fate of the King.

Gai also mentioned to Shu in the final battle that they would not allow Mana to just die in peace, they would keeping resurrecting her. Gai was in love with Mana and believed that to free her he must of offered to be her Adam and die with her.

Gai revealed to Shu that he was the true "King" and that Shu was nothing more than an Upsurper and pretty much this whole time was a victim in this whole mess that kept just getting chosen.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.